# Why Allow ADL lookup for template name binding?

Tags: c++

I Know for dependent names, the binding must be deferred to point of instantiation.
Think about the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> 
void g(T a)
{
    f(a);
}

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class X{};
    void f(X) {  cout << "f(X)\n"; }
}

void f(int i) { cout << "f(int)\n"; }

int main()
{
    g(MyNamespace::X{});   //1. print f(x)
    //g(1);                //2. not compile
    return 0;
}
```

for 1, all compilers I tested(VC++, gcc, clang) could find MyNamespace::f(X) by ADL. That's fine, it is in accordance with standard. However, gcc and clang cannot compile 2. because the standard does not allow directly searching functions in the instantiation context. That's the standard requires (Fine, vc++ violates the standard in this respect).

I know the standard does not allow searching functions in template instantiation context is a safeguard to ODR. However, why does it allow ADL examines function declarations that are visible from the template instantiation context? Will this cause violation of ODR as well? Consider the follow:

```
//ff.h
#include <iostream>

namespace N
{
    class X {};
    int g(X, int i);
}

template<typename T>
double ff(T t, double d)
{
    return g(t, d);
}

//ff.cpp
#include "ff.h"

int N::g(X, int i) { std::cout << "g(X,int)" << std::endl; return i; }

double x1 = ff(N::X{}, 1.1);

//main.cpp
#include "ff.h"

namespace N
{
    double g(X, double d) { std::cout << "g(X,double)" << std::endl; return d; }
}

auto x2 = ff(N::X{}, 2.2);

int main()
{
    extern double x1;
    std::cout<<"x1 = " << x1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "x2 = " << x2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There are two places that instantiate the function template ff： `ff(N::X, double)`, one in ff.cpp, one in main.cpp. In main.cpp, the namespace is changed and a better matching function `double g(X, double)` is added in main.cpp before the instantiation of ff. Therefore, the instantiation in main.cpp could pick up this better matching function`g`, anyway both `g` are equal in the scope of main.cpp. But the instantiation in ff.cpp could only choose the first `g` declared in ff.h. This obviously violates ODR, though I tested all 3 compilers pick up `int g(X, int)`, but that seems the compilers are smart enough to detect this illness in the generated code and optimized out the duplicated specialization. The compilers are not obliged to catch problems of this kind. So why standard allows ADL in this case, that could lead to potential violation to ODR?

Comment: In example 1 as `g()` is in the global scope `g(MyNamespace::X{});` does not invoke ADL.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main.cpp` does something untoward by defining a new overload for a function taking `N::X` in that namespace; this is usually considered part of the interface of `N::X` and should be declared whereever `N::X` is.  That logic doesn't apply to the normal lookup, since something declared in the global namespace after the template can't reasonably be assumed to be desired by the template author.